# Manipulate char vectors inside a data.table object in R

Tags: r, string, data.table, strsplit

I'm a bit new still to using data.table and understanding all its subtleties.
I've looked in the doc and in other examples in SO but couldn't find what I want, so please help !

I have a data.table which is basically a char vector (each entry being a sentence)

```
DT=c("I love you","she loves me")
DT=as.data.table(DT)
colnames(DT) <- "text"
setkey(DT,text)

# > DT
#            text
# 1:   I love you
# 2: she loves me
```

What I'd like to do, is to be able to perform some basic string operations inside the DT object. For example, add a new column where I would have a char vector for which each entry is a WORD from the string in the "text" column.

so I'd like to have for example a new column charvec where

```
> DT[1]$charvec
[1] "I" "love "you"
```

Of course, I would like to do it the data.table way, ultra-fast, because I need to do this kind of things on fils which are >1Go file, and use more complex and computation-heavy functions. So **no use of APPLY, LAPPLY, and MAPPLY**

My closest attempt to do something which looks like it is as follow:

```
myfun1 <- function(sentence){strsplit(sentence," ")}
DU1 <- DT[,myfun1(text),by=text]
DU2 <- DU1[,list(charvec=list(V1)),by=text]
# > DU2
#            text      charvec
# 1:   I love you   I,love,you
# 2: she loves me she,loves,me
```

For example, to make a function which removes the first word of each sentence, I did this

```
myfun2 <- function(l){l[[1]][-1]}
DV1 <- DU2[,myfun2(charvec),by=text]
DV2 <- DV1[,list(charvec=list(V1)),by=text]
# > DV2
#            text  charvec
# 1:   I love you love,you
# 2: she loves me loves,me
```

the trouble is, in the column charvec, i've got a list and not a vector...

```
> str(DU2[1]$charvec)
# List of 1
# $ : chr [1:3] "I" "love" "you"
```

1) how can i get to do what i want ?
other kind of functions i'm thinking to use is subsetting the char vector, or applying some hash to it, etc..

2) BTW, can I get to DU2 or DV2 in one line instead of two lines ?
3) i don't understand well the syntax for data.table. why is it that with the command `list()` inside the [..], the column V1 vanishes ?
4) on another thread, i read a bit about the function `cSplit`.

. is it any good ? is it a function adapted to data.table objects ?

thanks very much

**UPDATE**

thanks to @Ananda Mahto 
Perhaps i should make myself more clear of my ultimate objective
I have a huge file of 10,000,000 sentences stored as string.
As a first step for that project, I want to make a hash of the first 5 words of each sentence. 10,000,000 sentences wouldn't even get in my memory, so i did first split into 10 files of 1,000,000 sentences, that would be around a 10x 1Go files.
the following code takes several minutes on my laptop just for a single file.

```
library(data.table); library(digest);
num_row=1000000
DT <- fread("sentences.txt",nrows=num_row,header=FALSE,sep="\t",colClasses="character")
DT=as.data.table(DT)
colnames(DT) <- "text"
setkey(DT,text)
rawdata <- DT

hash2 <- function(word){ #using library(digest)
        as.numeric(paste("0x",digest(word,algo="murmur32"),sep=""))
}
```

then,

```
print(system.time({ 

        colnames(rawdata) <- "sentence"
        rawdata <- lapply(rawdata,strsplit," ")

        sentences_begin <- lapply(rawdata$sentence,function(x){x[2:6]})
        hash_list <- sapply(sentences_begin,hash2)
        # remove(rawdata)
})) ## end of print system.time for loading the data
```

I know I'm pushing here R to its limits, but i'm struggling to find faster implementations, and i was thinking about data.table features...hence all my questions

Here is an implementation excluding lapply, but its actually slower !

```
print(system.time({
myfun1 <- function(sentence){strsplit(sentence," ")}
DU1 <- DT[,myfun1(text),by=text]
DU2 <- DU1[,list(charvec=list(V1)),by=text]

myfun2 <- function(l){l[[1]][2:6]}
DV1 <- DU2[,myfun2(charvec),by=text]
DV2 <- DV1[,list(charvec=list(V1)),by=text]

rebuildsentence <- function(S){
        paste(S,collapse=" ") }

myfun3 <- function(l){hash2(rebuildsentence(l[[1]]))}

DW1 <- DV2[,myfun3(charvec),by=text]

})) #end of system.time
```

In this implementation with data file, no lapply, so i hoped the hashing would be faster. However because in every column i have a list instead of a char vector, this may slow significantly (?) the whole thing.

Using the first code above (with `lapply`/`sapply`) took more than 1 hour on my laptop. I hoped to speed that with a more efficient data structure ?. People using Python, Java etc... do a similar job in a few seconds.

Of course, another road would be to find a faster hash function but I assumed the one in `digest` package was already optimized.

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: as written above, the main goal is to avoid using lapply, sapply, mapply, use the data.table syntax only to manipulate very quickly a data.table of strings for large files (over 1Go, basically the maximum allowed by memory and speed....). I want to be able to convert to the column of strings into column of char vectors into the same table, and then to take a subset of it, like the first 5 words, or the last 5 words, i want to calculate the hash of those 5 words, or the hash of the full sentence...I've done that *not* using data.table , and lapply style, it took several minutes. way too long.

Comment: for my education, from the table DU2 and its second column (every element is a list) how would u reconstruct the original text (single string) ?

Comment: Have you tried a regex solution to extract the first five words and directly make a hash of that?

Comment: @AnandaMahto what is regex ?

Comment: Regular expression. Not in front of a computer right now so can't propose a solution....

Comment: Also, have you tried profiling your code to figure out where the slowdown is taking place?

Comment: Check out "Update 2" and let me know if that is helpful....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're after, but you can try `cSplit_l` from my "splitstackshape" package to get to your list column:

```
library(splitstackshape)
DU <- cSplit_l(DT, "DT", " ")
```

Then, you can write a function like the following to remove values from the list column:

```
RemovePos <- function(inList, pos = 1) {
  lapply(inList, function(x) x[-c(pos[pos <= length(x)])])
}
```

Example usage:

```
DU[, list(RemovePos(DT_list, 1)), by = DT]
#              DT       V1
# 1:   I love you love,you
# 2: she loves me loves,me
DU[, list(RemovePos(DT_list, 2)), by = DT]
#              DT     V1
# 1:   I love you  I,you
# 2: she loves me she,me
DU[, list(RemovePos(DT_list, c(1, 2))), by = DT]
#              DT  V1
# 1:   I love you you
# 2: she loves me  me
```

---

#### Update

Based on your loathe of `lapply, maybe you can try something like the following:

```
## make a copy of your "text" column
DT[, vals := text]

## Use `cSplit` to create a "long" dataset. 
## Add a column to indicate the word's position in the text.
DTL <- cSplit(DT, "vals", " ", "long")[, ind := sequence(.N), by = text][]
DTL
#            text  vals ind
# 1:   I love you     I   1
# 2:   I love you  love   2
# 3:   I love you   you   3
# 4: she loves me   she   1
# 5: she loves me loves   2
# 6: she loves me    me   3

## Now, you can extract values easily
DTL[ind == 1]
#            text vals ind
# 1:   I love you    I   1
# 2: she loves me  she   1
DTL[ind %in% c(1, 3)]
#            text vals ind
# 1:   I love you    I   1
# 2:   I love you  you   3
# 3: she loves me  she   1
# 4: she loves me   me   3
```

---

#### Update 2

I don't know what type of timings you are getting, but as I mentioned in a comment, you can perhaps try using regular expressions so that you don't have to split and then paste the string back together.

Here's a sample....

Set up some data to play with:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
  text = c("This is a sentence with a lot of words.",
           "This is a sentence with some more words.",
           "Words and words and even some more words.",
           "But, I don't know how you want to deal with punctuation...",
           "Just one more sentence, for easy multiplication.")
)

DT2 <- rbindlist(replicate(10000/nrow(DT), DT, FALSE))
DT3 <- rbindlist(replicate(1000000/nrow(DT), DT, FALSE))
```

Test the gsub pattern to extract 5 words from each sentence....

```
## Regex to extract first five words -- this should work....
patt <- "^((?:\\S+\\s+){4}\\S+).*"

## Check out some of the timings
system.time(temp <- DT2[, gsub(patt, "\\1", text)])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.03    0.00    0.03 
system.time(temp2 <- DT3[, gsub(patt, "\\1", text)])
#    user  system elapsed 
#       3       0       3 
head(temp)
# [1] "This is a sentence with"     "This is a sentence with"     "Words and words and even"   
# [4] "But, I don't know how"       "Just one more sentence, for" "This is a sentence with"
```

My guess at what you're looking to do....

```
## I'm assuming you want something like this....
## Takes about a minute on my system. 
## ... but note the system time for the creation of "temp2" (without digest)
## Not sure if I interpreted your hash requirement correctly....
system.time(out <- DT3[
  , firstFive := gsub(patt, "\\1", text)][
  , firstFiveHash := hash2(firstFive), by = 1:nrow(DT3)][])
#    user  system elapsed 
#   62.14    0.05   62.20 

head(out)
#                                                          text                   firstFive firstFiveHash
# 1:                    This is a sentence with a lot of words.     This is a sentence with    4179639471
# 2:                   This is a sentence with some more words.     This is a sentence with    4179639471
# 3:                  Words and words and even some more words.    Words and words and even    2556713080
# 4: But, I don't know how you want to deal with punctuation...       But, I don't know how    3765680401
# 5:           Just one more sentence, for easy multiplication. Just one more sentence, for     298317689
# 6:                    This is a sentence with a lot of words.     This is a sentence with    4179639471
```

Comment: i don't want any solution using lapply, mapply, or sapply. I want to use the data.table syntax. it is documented that those functions are obsolete with data.table and should *never* be used when looking for performance (or "pure efficient R code) look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf

Comment: @FaguiCurtain, use `cSplit` with the "long" direction, add a numeric index using `.N`, and then you can subset based on the value created by `.N`. I'm not sure where you get the idea that `lapply` has been made obsolete by "data.table" and should *never* be used with "data.table".

Comment: Indeed, `*apply` functions are an efficient way of getting things done *within* `data.table` syntax. You may want to check https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks for your time. I don't know what you're trying to do with the command `gsub` ?. I don't understand also the syntax of your last line. in the column first Five, i see more than 5 words. also, to make the problem simpler, in the original file i was working with, there was only space, no other punctuation.

Comment: what does the triple column `:::` mean ?

Comment: @FaguiCurtain, please try based on my most recent edit. The `:::` is to access non-exported functions (like `trim`) but that is not required with the update I've added.

Comment: thanks Ananda for all your answers. Your implementation doesn't work faster, but still i learnt many useful things today thanks to your help.i think there is no other way than to find a faster hash function !