# REGEX in R: extracting words from a string

Tags: regex, r, string, extract

i guess this is a common problem, and i found quite a lot of webpages, including some from SO, but i failed to understand how to implement it.

I am new to REGEX, and I'd like to use it in R to extract the first few words from a sentence.

for example, if my sentence is

```
z = "I love stack overflow it is such a cool site"
```

id like to have my output as being (if i need the first four words)

```
[1] "I love stack overflow"
```

or (if i need the last four words)

```
[1] "such a cool site"
```

of course, the following works

```
paste(strsplit(z," ")[[1]][1:4],collapse=" ")
paste(strsplit(z," ")[[1]][7:10],collapse=" ")
```

but i'd like to try a regex solution for performance issues as i need to deal with very huge files (and also for the sake of knowing about it)

I looked at several links, including
[Regex to extract first 3 words from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345973/regex-to-extract-first-3-words-from-a-string) and
http://osherove.com/blog/2005/1/7/using-regex-to-return-the-first-n-words-in-a-string.html

so i tried things like

```
gsub("^((?:\S+\s+){2}\S+).*",z,perl=TRUE)
Error: '\S' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""^((?:\S"
```

i tried other stuff but it usually returned me either the whole string, or the empty string.

another problem with substr is that it returns a list. maybe it looks like the `[[]]` operator is slowing things a bit (??) when dealing with large files and doing apply stuff.

it looks like the Syntax used in R is somewhat different ?
thanks !

Comment: You need to use double escapes in R regex. `\S` -> `\\S`

Comment: You could also try `stringi::stri_extract_all_words(z)[[1]][1:4]` which is easier to use and doesn't require to know regex. Though you will get the words a separate values.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the same idea that I had shared [in your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785594/manipulate-char-vectors-inside-a-data-table-object-in-r)? You just need to double up on your backslashes in R, as already pointed out by @stribizhev.

Comment: yes @Ananda Mahto sorry, i am slow to learn, now i understand I need the double backslash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've already accepted an answer, but I'm going to share this as a means of helping you understand a little more about regex in R, since you were actually very close to getting the answer on your own.

---

There are two problems with your `gsub` approach:

1. You used single backslashes (`\`). R requires you to escape those since they are special characters. You escape them by adding another backslash (`\\`). If you do `nchar("\\")`, you'll see that it returns "1".
2. You didn't specify what the replacement should be. Here, we don't want to replace anything, but we want to capture a specific part of the string. You capture groups in parentheses `(...)`, and then you can refer to them by the number of the group. Here, we have just one group, so we refer to it as `"\\1"`.

You should have tried something like:

```
sub("^((?:\\S+\\s+){2}\\S+).*", "\\1", z, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "I love stack"
```

This is essentially saying:

- Work from the start of the contents of "z".
- Start creating group 1.
- Find non-whitespace (like a word) followed by whitespace (`\S+\s+`) two times `{2}` and then the next set of non-whitespaces (`\S+`). This will get us 3 words, without also getting the whitespace after the third word. Thus, if you wanted a different number of words, change the `{2}` to be one less than the number you are actually after.
- End group 1 there.
- Then, just return the contents of group 1 (`\1`) from "z".

---

To get the last three words, just switch the position of the capturing group and put it at the end of the pattern to match.

```
sub("^.*\\s+((?:\\S+\\s+){2}\\S+)$", "\\1", z, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "a cool site"
```

Comment: thanks. @Ananda Mahto. could you give the regex for the last 4 words using the same function `sub` ?

Comment: @FaguiCurtain, I just swapped the reference from being fixed to the start of the line to the end instead, like: `^.*((?:\\S+\\s+){2}\\S+)$`. Change "2" to "3" to get 4 words instead of 3.

Answer (score 3):

For getting the first four words.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "^\\s*(?:\\S+\\s+){3}\\S+")
```

For getting the last four.

```
str_extract(x, "(?:\\S+\\s+){3}\\S+(?=\\s*$)")
```

Comment: or `sub("^\\s*((?:\\S+\\s+){3}\\S+).*", "\\1", x)`

Comment: can you give me the correct regex using the function `sub`. i made a test on a 10,000 sample and the `sub` function from base R is like 30 times faster than `str_extract` from the `library(stringr)`. thanks

Comment: I'm stupid but don't know how to tweak the function. `sub("(?:\\S+\\s+){3}\\S+(?=\\s*$)",replacement="",z,perl=TRUE)` is returning me `"I love stack overflow it is "` which is everything BUT the last 4 words...

Comment: `sub('^.* (\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s+\\w+)$', '\\1', z)` works for the last 5 strings, but i don't understand how to use properly the `{...}` to make for a simpler expression in this case

Comment: like `sub('^.* (\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+){4})$', '\\1', z)`